# Optimise array calculation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, fenwick-tree

#### The task:

You are given an array `a` of `0 < N ≤ 100000` elements and `0 < M ≤ 100000` queries. Each query can be one of two types:

`? l r k` — REQ(l, r, k)

or

`+ i delta` — inc(i, delta): increase `a[i]` value by delta.

It is guaranteed that elements of array never exceed `K`, that is, `0 ≤ a[i] ≤ K`.

**Input format:**

- The first line contains 3 integers `N`, `M`, and `K`, where `0 < N, M ≤ 100000` and `0 < K ≤ 100`. `N` is the number of items in the array, `M` is the number of queries and `K` is an upper bound on the values in the array.
- The next line contains `N` integer numbers — the values of the array `a`, where `0 ≤ a[i] ≤ K`
- Each of next `M` lines contains one character followed by 3 or 4 integer numbers — the request can be one of two types:

`? l r k` — REQ(l, r, k): `0 ≤ l < r ≤ N`, `0 ≤ k ≤ K`

or

`+ i delta` — inc(i, delta): increase `a[i]` value by delta, `0 ≤ i < N`, `-K ≤ k ≤ K`

**Output format:**

For each "?" query provide answer for REQ request.

**Input sample:**

```
2 8 1
0 0
? 0 2 0
? 0 2 1
+ 0 1
? 0 2 0
? 0 2 1
+ 1 1
? 0 2 0
? 0 2 1
```

**Output:**

```
2
0
1
1
0
2
```

#### The code:

```
import sys


class FenwickTree:
    def __init__(self, n, k, tree):
        self.n = n
        self.k = k
        self.tree = tree

    def add(self, i, delta):
        self.tree[i] += delta

    def sum(self, fr, to, val):
        return self.tree[fr:to].count(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
    n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))

    ft = FenwickTree(n, k, a)

    for _ in range(m):
        op = input().split()
        if op[0] == '?':
            print(ft.sum(int(op[1]), int(op[2]), int(op[3])))
        else:
            ft.add(int(op[1]), int(op[2]))
```

I look to optimise the code above, as it doesn't fit into a time limit.

Comment: Here's an idea: use a Fenwick tree.

Comment: Your tree code doesn't really implement a tree. Labeling an array with a variable named `tree` doesn't convert it into a tree.